# Is it possible to add shape to existing image in Excel

Tags: excel, image

Is it possible to insert shape and add the shape to already existing picture inserted from a file like PNG, JPG, GIF. I am looking for merging the shape and the picture in ONE image, not just grouping them together.

Alternatively is there a way to group two objects in Excel permanently so that no ungrouping is possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to draw images in Excel. You can only import images.

Comment: How can you say it so authoritatively without any doubt? Can you link to any documentation? Or maybe you just think it is not possible? There are many ways to modify picture in MS Excel (like brightness contrast). It is possible to insert a shape of Scribble. Maybe there is some gate left open to do what I want?

Comment: I have reworded my question. I cannot see anything which might help using shapes on pictures inserted to Excel. I know the Shapes and how to use them.